# ASP.NET Core Identity seed data is not persisted to database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a new ASP.NET RazorPages project. I've overridden `IdentityUser` and now it's time to add some base data.

It's not possible to do this in SQL because that can't hash the password, so it has to be done via C#.

There's lots of misinformation around about 'seed data', but I haven't got anything to work.

The only thing I can think to do is add a method in `Startup.cs` that checks to see whether or not the base data is there and if not then add it. Is that really how it's done?

There's a lot of talk about migrations but I can't see anything in the `Migration` class for adding seed data.

Similarly, there is a lot of mention of `Entity<Foo>().HasData(new Foo(...))` and I have tried this however the data is not actually added to the database.

What am I *supposed* to be doing?

Comment: Given that you are talking about "Entity" and "Migrations," can we assume that you are using Entity Framework? Which .Net Core version?

Comment: Besides,please share your model and how do you seed data.And what is your error message?For more details about seed data,refer to:https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding

Answer (score 0):

Generally to clear up a few stuff

> There's a lot of talk about migrations but I can't see anything in the Migration class for adding seed data.

Migrations is about the DB schema. When you make change a table, add remove columns etc, the migrations have to be applied to update your schema. So it has nothing to do with data other than the fact that some migrations may need special care (for example making a Nullable column Non null).

> What am I supposed to be doing?

You want to start saving data to your DB as you would normally. Create a class or a different class library which will be responsible for seeding your data and the you will call it from your `Startup.cs`. An example of how the code would look for a simple example.

```
var foos = new List<Foo>()
{
   new Foo(1), new Foo(2)
}

services.AddFoos(foos);
```

You want to use your services (I assusme you use dependency injection) so just instantiate them and then call them. For example you could use `usermanager` class to insert the data.